# How to get iOS appex file using CMake

Tags: ios, cmake

I am trying to get iOS *.appex output using CMake.

```
#CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(ExtensionProject)

add_library(MyAppExtension MODULE Extension.h Extension.mm)

set_target_properties(MyAppExtension PROPERTIES
                      BUNDLE YES
                      MACOS_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist
                      XCODE_PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.app-extension)
```

I have referenced the page below.

- https://github.com/IMcD23/NSExtension-Demo
- https://ianmcdowell.net/blog/nsextension/

[image: Info.plist]

[image: Extension.mm]

I have succeeded in creating non-ui extensions using XCode!!!

But when using CMake, *.bundle is created, not *appex file. What am I missing?

Comment: The default extension for BUNDLE target is `.bundle` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/prop_tgt/BUNDLE_EXTENSION.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use add_executable, not add_library.